# Azure API management: Set different backend url for different endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I have an Azure API which have multiple endpoints and it calls different backend service with different api-keys.
Eg:

1. /offer endpoint in azure apim calls : https://offerBackend/offers
2. /offer/{id} - https://offerBackend/offers/{id}
3. /products - https://productBackend/products
4. /customer - https://customerBackend/customer

I am trying to use set-backend-service based on the endpoint being called, like:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Start:Set Different backends on basis of endpoints -->
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("offer"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://offerBackend" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("product"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://productBackend" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("customer"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://customerBackend" />
            </when>
        <!-- End:Set Different backends on basis of endpoints -->
    </inbound>
```

But for these different backends I need to pass different credentials i.e. api-key in header.How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `when` elements do not have the parent element [choose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#choose).
Example:

```xml
<choose>
    <when condition="Boolean expression | Boolean constant">
        <!— one or more policy statements to be applied if the above condition is true  -->
    </when>
    <when condition="Boolean expression | Boolean constant">
        <!— one or more policy statements to be applied if the above condition is true  -->
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <!— one or more policy statements to be applied if none of the above conditions are true  -->
    </otherwise>
</choose>
```

---

You can specify the api-keys as [named values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties?tabs=azure-portal) to store them as secrets:

[image]

The named value can be used as header value for authentication to the backend:

```xml
<set-header name="api-key" exists-action="override">
   <value>{{offer-api-key}}</value>
</set-header>
<set-backend-service base-url="https://offerBackend" />
```

The complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Start:Set Different backends on basis of endpoints -->
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("offer"))">
                <set-header name="api-key" exists-action="override">
                    <value>{{offer-api-key}}</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://offerBackend" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("product"))">
                <set-header name="api-key" exists-action="override">
                    <value>{{product-api-key}}</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://productBackend" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("customer"))">
                <set-header name="api-key" exists-action="override">
                    <value>{{customer-api-key}}</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://customerBackend" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <!-- End:Set Different backends on basis of endpoints -->
    </inbound>
```

A different solution is, to use [backends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/backends) and configure URL, authentication, ... in one place:

[image]

This can be used in the [set-backend-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService)  policy

```xml
<when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("offer"))">
      <set-backend-service backend-id="Offer" />
</when>
```

The complete inbound policy with Backend-Ids:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Start:Set Different backends on basis of endpoints -->
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("offer"))">
                <set-backend-service backend-id="Offer" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("product"))">
                <set-backend-service backend-id="Product" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("customer"))">
                <set-backend-service backend-id="Customer" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <!-- End:Set Different backends on basis of endpoints -->
    </inbound>
```

Comment: Thanks @Markus for your answer, I will give it a try. Indeed I missed choose tag initially